# Getting DISTINCT values from object array using the index in Cosmos db

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a container with ~9000 documents like this (simplified for brevity):

```
{
    "id": "111",
    "productid": "111"
    "data": {
        "Channel": "All",
        "Headline": [
            {
                "Culture": "en",
                "Value": "English name"
            },
            {
                "Culture": "da",
                "Value": "Danish name"
            }
        ]
   }
}
```

If I want to the get the DISTINCT `Channel` values, then I can do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT VALUE c.data.Channel FROM c
```

This query costs me ~5 RUs and does not retrieve any documents, but gives me the values I need.

If I wanted to get all the DISTINCT `Culture` values, then the similiar query does not return anything:

```
SELECT DISTINCT VALUE c.data.Headline.Culture FROM c
```

I can change that query to JOIN the Headline, and get the results I want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT VALUE h.Culture FROM c JOIN h IN c.data.Headline
```

However, the above query costs ~4800 RUs, and retrieves all 9000 documents along the way behind the scenes. Even though all properties are indexed on the document.

Is there a way to make this DISTINCT work for a property on an array of objects?

Or do I have to add a new `data.HeadlineCultures[]` string array, and use that instead?

UPDATE: I just tried creating a `data.HeadlineCultures[]` string array, and that has the exact same issues as a complex array object, so this is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query directly instead of using `JOIN`.

```
SELECT  distinct  value h.Culture FROM h IN c.data.Headline
```

Before taking distinct.

[image]

After taking the distinct.
[image]

Comment: The focus of the question was RU consumption. How does this stack up for that?

Comment: The queries involving joins and retrieving large data, requires more RUs. Compare the RU consumption on query resulting same output with join and without join.

Comment: Using this query on my data actually increased the RU usage by 37%.